# network backend 'user' is not compiled into this binary

Tags: qemu, configure, qemu-device-backend

I have build `qemu-7.2.0` and then, when running it I am getting

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -nic user,model=virtio: network backend 'user' is not compiled into this binary
```

Apparently, I should enable this feature during build, but how to know which is it namely?

Answer (score 10):

The 'user' networking backend is provided by the 'slirp' library; you get this message when the QEMU binary was built without slirp support compiled in.

As noted in [the 7.2 changelog](https://wiki.qemu.org/ChangeLog/7.2#SLIRP_module_(user-mode_networking)), QEMU no longer ships a copy of the slirp module with its sources. Instead you need to make sure you have installed your distro's libslirp development package (which is probably called libslirp-devel or libslirp-dev or something similar) before configuring and building QEMU. You need at least libslirp 4.7 or better.

QEMU's configure convention for optional features which require some build-time dependency is:

- by default, check for the dependency, and build in the feature if we find it
- if --enable-foo is passed, check for the dependency, and fail configure with an error if it is missing
- if --disable-foo is passed, don't check, and never build in the feature

So you can pass configure `--enable-slirp` to force it to give you an error if you haven't got the dependency, as a way of checking that you've installed the right system package for libslirp.

Comment: Can you elaborate please, where did `slirp` arose from?

Comment: It's a library that was originally part of QEMU proper but has been spun out into its own project : https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/slirp/libslirp

Comment: But how is it related to my question? `slirp` is not mentionned in error message

Comment: slirp is the library that provides the 'user' networking backend

Comment: How is it knowable? I think other times I didn't do anything, but `user` network was working? Can it be?

Comment: If you were using an older QEMU it had the submodule so it would have automatically compiled it in. Now it doesn't, so you need to install the dependency. I agree that the error message is a bit unhelpful.

Comment: @Peter - thanks for keeping QEMU cats corralled!

Answer (score 0):

$ git clone https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu.git

$ sudo apt-get install git libglib2.0-dev libfdt-dev libpixman-1-dev zlib1g-dev ninja-build meson

$ git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/slirp/libslirp.git

$ cd libslirp

$ meson build

$ ninja -C build install

$ cd ..

$ cd qemu

$ mkdir -p bin/debug/native

$ cd bin/debug/native

$ ../../.././configure --enable-slirp --enable-debug

$ make -j$(nproc)

$ make install

$ cd ../../..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).